# Help understanding proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus part 2

Tags: calculus

My calculus book has a proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus for continuous functions.  I've been confused on one part though.  How do they get the equation after "Thus, if $|h| < \delta$, we have"?  I get that they just integrated the previous equation, but why does that follow because $|h| < \delta$ ?

[image: math]
[image: math]

Comment: Because inequality in the previous equation only holds if $|t-x|<\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered in a comment:

> Because inequality in the previous equation only holds if $|t−x|<\delta$. –  IBWiglin Jan 15 at 19:53